# How put css on django?

Tags: css, django, django-templates

I have a big problem.Django doesn't recognize my css files. [PHG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vrUG.png)

My css file is located in `polls`, but Django won't recognize it as a static file

My home.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">

<title>121212</title>
<body>
    <div id="1212">
        <li class="fafa">12112</li>
    </div>
</body>
```

my settings.py

````
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very **SMALL** problem, **Mr XD**.

In your template: `{% load static %}`

And then: `<link href="{% static 'home.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: `{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">

<title>121212</title>
<body>
    <div id="1212">
        <li class="fafa">12112</li>
    </div>
</body>`

Comment: NO)I forget...{% load static %} already have been in my template)BUT it isnt work)

Comment: href="{% static 'home.css' %}"

Comment: thanks you.But I repaired it long ago.I enabled "debug mode".